# How can telnetd-ssl be set up on an Ubuntu server as a backup to SSH?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssl, telnet

An error arising in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` can potentially lock users or administrators out of a server that is accessible only via SSH. Telnet SSL is a backup way of accessing the server in such a scenario. How can a Telnet SSL server be set up on an Ubuntu server?

Telnet SSL is installed in the following way:

```
sudo apt install telnetd-ssl
```

When it is installed, it creates the certificate `/etc/telnetd-ssl/telnetd.pem`. When the Telnet SSL client attempts to connect to the Telnet SSL server, it does not accept the certificate, resulting in client output like the following:

```
$ telnet-ssl -z secure example.org 23
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to example.org.
Escape character is '^]'.
[SSL - attempting to switch on SSL]
[SSL - handshake starting]
SSL: Server has a self-signed certificate
SSL: unknown issuer: /O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd/OU=m93p telnetd/CN=example./emailAddress=root@example.
SSL: certificate verify failed
telnet: Unable to ssl_connect to remote host
Connection closed.
```

How can this be addressed?

Comment: An error in `sshd_config` will not affect existing connections, making it easy to test changes by opening a second session after restarting `sshd`.

Answer (score 1):

> Telnet SSL server, it does not accept the certificate, resulting in
>   client output like the following:
>
> ```
> $ telnet-ssl -z secure example.org 23
> ...
> SSL: Server has a self-signed certificate
> SSL: unknown issuer: /O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd/OU=m93p telnetd/CN=example./emailAddress=root@example.
> SSL: certificate verify failed
> ```

According to the [`telnet-ssl(1)` man pages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/telnet-ssl.1.html), it looks like you need a `-z cert=<cert file>` option.

`-z cert=<cert file>` is needed because the Issuer (Subject DN = `/O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd/OU=m93p telnetd/CN=example./emailAddress=root@example`) is not trusted by the system. That is, the certificate does not reside in `/etc/ssl/certs/`.

Another option may be to add the certificate to `/etc/ssl/certs/`. For Debian and Ubuntu you just copy new certificate in PEM format to the directory `/etc/ssl/certs/`. The new certificate will reside side-by-side with the other 450 or so certificates.

For Fedora you have to append the new certificate to the file `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt`. `ca-bundle.crt` is really a link to `/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem`. `tls-ca-bundle.pem` is just a concatenation of the PEM files into a single file.

Fedora also has a `/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/openssl/ca-bundle.trust.crt`, but I don't believe you would use it because `ca-bundle.trust.crt` is for CA's, and the self-signed end-entity certificate should *not* have `CA=TRUE` in Basic Constraints.

---

It is worth mentioning that I have never used `telnet-ssl` so I can't provide a complete answer based on experience. You will likely encounter additional issues once you get beyond "trust this SSL certificate". For example, it looks like Telnet over TLS uses port 992, not 23.

Comment: f.y.i.: The current telnet-ssl and telnetd-ssl default configuration will use the standard telnet port 23 and opportunistically invoke an SSL connection with fallback to a straight non-encrypted telnet session.  [ At least on debian based [ubuntu, devuan, raspbian, etc... distributions.  Maybe others? ]